# python itertools groupby find the max value

Tags: python-2.7, group-by, python-itertools

use:

```
from itertools  import groupby

from operater import itemgetter
```

like this:

input:

```
test = {('a','b'):1,('a','c'):2,('a','d'):3,('x','b'):4,('x','c'):5}
```

find the max value groupby the key[0]

output:

```
output_test = {('a','d'):3,('x','c'):5}
```

Comment: sorry,clerical error

Comment: What about the case `[(('a','b'), 1), (('x','c'), 5), (('a','b'), 2)]`? What is the reason for `groupby`? Is it a requirement?

Comment: groupby the  first item of dict key

Comment: {(|'a'|,'b'):1,(|'a'|,'c'):2,(|'a'|,'d'):3,(|'x'|,'b'):4,(|'x'|,'c'):5}  groupby this about use || mark and find the dict  max value

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered containers, however, `groupby` works with sorted data. There is no reason for `groupby` here.

Comment: then how to do get the max item

Answer (score 1):

To do this using `itetools.groupby` and assuming you do not care which entry is returned if there are multiple entries with the same max value:

```
test = {('a', 'b'): 1, ('a', 'c'): 2, ('a', 'd'): 3, ('x', 'b'): 4, ('x', 'c'): 5}
output_test = {('a', 'd'): 3, ('x', 'c'): 5}

grouped = itertools.groupby(sorted(test.iteritems()), lambda x: x[0][0])
maxEntries = {x[0]: x[1] for x in {max(v, key=lambda q: q[1]) for k, v in grouped}}

print maxEntries
print maxEntries == output_test
```

Outputs:

```
{('x', 'c'): 5, ('a', 'd'): 3}
True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools  import groupby
max([sum(1 for _ in g) for k, g in groupby(input)])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.